# How do I make an application beep when I click on it to launch it?

Tags: desktop, lxde, icons

Summary:

I use Debian with LXDE desktop environment. On the Panel that runs along the
bottom of the desktop, there are small program icons (such as for File Manager,
Konsole, Kate editor). When I single-click on them, the application should be
launched.

Could you tell me please, how to cause a beep to occur when my click has truly
caused the application to launch.

Full Details:

The reason that I want to do the above is because often, when I click on one of
these icons, NOTHING HAPPENS. The application doesn't launch (after waiting the
usual few seconds for it to launch). So I have to click a second time on the
icon to make it launch.

Sometimes, when the mouse pointer is over the icon, the "description bubble"
appears (you know, saying what that icon launches). I get the feeling that
sometimes (not always) that this bubble is interfering with the clicking on
the icon, perhaps stopping the click being registered.

So I'd like to HEAR a beep to tell me that the application has definitely been
launched. This is so that if it HASN'T been launched, I can click the icon
again straight away, and don't have to wait a few seconds to discover that it
wasn't launched.

Comment: You know, it sounds like you really ought to be asking for how to fix the "sometimes, my click is ignored" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use KDE, maybe it is similar to LXDE?
Go to System Settings, find Application and System Notifications. All you need is in there.

Also, if you want to know whether it has clicked or not, you can use bouncing mouse instead of sound. Sound will make distracting. I hate Facebook sound :D

To do this, find Launch Feedback in System Settings. You will find this (cool) feature.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like `application_command && play beep_file`.